# Laravel Seed Multiple Relations

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-seeding

I have 3 models: `Member`, `Invoice` and `Payment`

Here is the `Member` model:

```
class Member extends Model
{
     public function invoice()
     {
          return $this->hasOne(Invoice::class);
     }
}
```

And in the `Invoice` model:

```
class Invoice extends Model
{
     public function member()
     {
        return $this->belongsTo(Member::class, 'member_id');
     }

     public function payments()
     {
        return $this->hasMany(Payment::class, 'invoice_id');
     }
}
```

And lastly, the `Payment` model:

```
class Payment extends Model
{
     public function invoice()
     {
          return $this->belongsTo(Invoice::class, 'invoice_id');
     }
}
```

Now, in my seeder, I want to create a Payment for each Invoice of each Member:

```
public function run()
{
   factory(Member::class, 100)->create()->each(function ($m) {
       $m->invoice()->save(factory(App\Invoice::class)->create()->each(function ($i) {
           $i->payments()->save(factory(App\Payment::class)->make());
     }));
  });
}
```

But it returns an error when I try to seed:

```
Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError  : Type error: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOneOrMany::save() must be an instance of Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model, boolean given
```

How can I achieve my desired output?

Answer (score 3):

Refer - [Factory Callbacks](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/database-testing#factory-callbacks) and [saveMany function](https://laravel.com/api/5.6/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/HasOne.html#method_saveMany)

Now, In your **MemberFactory.php**, add this

```
$factory->afterCreating(App\Member::class, function ($member, $faker) {
  $member->invoice()->save(factory(App\Invoice::class)->make());
});
```

In you **InvoiceFactory.php**, add this

```
$factory->afterMaking(App\Invoice::class, function ($invoice, $faker) {
  $invoice->payments()->saveMany(factory(App\Payment::class, 5)->make());
});
```

Finally, in your `run()` function, do

```
public function run()
{
  factory(Member::class, 100)->create();
}
```

Haven't tested, but should work :)

Also, I don't think you need the second parameters in your relation. The function should automatically be able to get the foreign key match if you are using singular nomenclature.

Comment: How would I pass the columns like `id` and `downpayment` from `InvoiceFactory` to `PaymentFactory` ?

Comment: What do you mean by pass `id` & `downpayment`? invoice_id will automatically be added in the payments table, right? What will the `downpayment` be used for?

Comment: I will use the `invoice->downpayment` to a column in `payment`

Comment: Can you try and pass `['columnName' => $invoice->downpayment]` to `make()` method? I am not sure but as per the docs it should work

Answer (score 0):

In you seed/Databaseeder.php (tested in Laravel 7)

```
public function run()
    {
        factory(App\Member::class, 100)->create()->each(function ($m) {
            // Seed the relation with one address
            $invoice = factory(App\Invoice::class)->make();
            $payments = factory(App\Payment::class,5)->make();
            $m->invoice()-save($invoice);
            $invoice->payments()->saveMany($payments)
        });
    }
```

The `run` function represent create 100 instance of member model for each member model create one invoice model and for each invoice create 5 payments model